# Including the weights argument in gam() and glmmTMB() yields significant p-values even with random data

Tags: r, p-value

I'm analysing the effect of `x` (proportion) on `y` (proportion) with a random effect `RE` (categorical). I using the `beta regression` family and `logit` link. I'm investigating the reliability of the `summary` p-value. I've done this by creating some random x-values and running the exact same analysis as on my real data. Against my expectations, the p-value was also very significant with randomly generated x-values. Then I started experimenting with different models, excluding arguments etc. I've boiled it down to the `weights =` argument, which makes the model either very significant, or not at all if not included. I have no clue why this would be the case, and how I could get around this problem. Below I have provided some data and code.

```r
library(mgcv)
library(glmmTMB)

rm(list = ls())

df <- data.frame(y = c(0.661904761904762, 0.406192519926425, 0.694285714285714, 0.0142857142857143, 0.0142857142857143, 0.0584415584415584, 0.257142857142857, 0.701154401154401, 0.625521669341894, 0.871428571428571, 0.930204081632653, 0.452995391705069, 0.0483709273182957, 0.5, 0.484821428571429, 0.0142857142857143, 0.0345238095238095, 0.248148148148148, 0.795866569978245, 0.661904761904762, 0.985714285714286, 0.985714285714286, 0.985714285714286, 0.550746268656716, 0.208571428571429, 0.0142857142857143, 0.0142857142857143, 0.0142857142857143, 0.0142857142857143, 0.0142857142857143, 0.14030888030888, 0.101142857142857, 0.573982970671712, 0.0142857142857143, 0.0142857142857143),
                 pointWeight = c(3, 233, 10, 89, 4, 22, 44, 99, 89, 17, 35, 341, 57, 36, 128, 39, 144, 54, 394, 12, 46, 229, 55, 67, 5, 28, 2, 160, 124, 294, 555, 425, 302, 116, 48),
                 Random_x = c(0.413296794, 0.347613463, 0.349795504, 0.961276169, 0.95789013, 0.035865447, 0.324590684, 0.44398489, 0.199835127, 0.53304746, 0.03317392, 0.9666195, 0.306412904, 0.208397613, 0.461614514, 0.209814992, 0.136107136, 0.107251692, 0.742954177, 0.620547648, 0.724865263, 0.290264773, 0.877152686, 0.26345651, 0.113437669, 0.333750829, 0.167373418, 0.431189319, 0.158608563, 0.026153635, 0.443326766, 0.450652285, 0.787105741, 0.833940574, 0.040695708),
                 RE = c("M", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "K", "K", "K", "K", "K", "K", "K", "K", "K", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "ME", "ME", "ME", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "V", "V", "K"))

# Using gam()
# With the 'weights =' agrument included.
mygam1 <- mgcv::gam(y ~ Random_x + s(RE, bs="re"), family=betar(link="logit"), data = df, weights = pointWeight)
summary(mygam1)
# Random_x: P value < 0.001

# Without the 'weights =' agrument.
mygam2 <- mgcv::gam(y ~ Random_x + s(RE, bs="re"), family=betar(link="logit"), data = df)
summary(mygam2)
# Random_x: P value = 0.945

# Using glmmTMB()
# With the 'weights =' agrument included.
myglmm1 <- glmmTMB(y ~ Random_x + (1|RE), data = df, beta_family(link = "logit"), weights = pointWeight)
summary(myglmm1)
# Random_x: P value < 0.001

# Without the 'weights =' agrument.
myglmm2 <- glmmTMB(y ~ Random_x + (1|RE), data = df, beta_family(link = "logit"))
summary(myglmm2)
# Random_x: P value = 0.855
```

The data looks like this, so you would definitely not expect a significant relationship between x and y. 
[image]

Does anyone know what the problem is here? Why is there such a big difference in significance by either including or excluding the `weights` argument? I understand that it influences the model, but here it means that both models are significant, while it clearly shouldn't be. Does it have to do with my weights?

Comment: Hi Peter.. thanks for sharing the data. I am not sure how you generate the random x values, but what happens is that the regression forces a line through the heavily weighted data points

Comment: You can very quickly see this withplot(df$Random_x,df$y,cex=df$pointWeight^0.3) ; points(df$Random_x,exp(predict(myglmm1,df)),col="red")

Comment: And if you look at your weights, they are not equally distributed across your RE,  tapply(df$pointWeight,df$RE,mean), meaning for some of them, it is going to weigh more

Comment: I would focus less on the p-value for the time being and ask whether it makes sense to fit like this, using the weights as they are.. Maybe scaling the weights is one option to mitigate their effect..

Comment: Thanks a lot. Scaling the weights was the solution. Now it works perfectly. However, it still seems weird that such solid models like ```gam()``` and ```glmmTMB()``` don't properly work with high value weights. I would expect that these models would run the same on rescaled weights as they do on the absolute weights, expecting that they always would use the relative values. However, I now know that this is not the case and I should rescale my weights in the future. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You're welcome :) I think it happens with all regression, once you include weights it gets a bit tricky.